# How can I add a variable as my key to a map?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I want to add a variable as my key to a map that I will add to an array in firebase.

Here's the code:

```
const groupUID = snapshot.id;
for (let members of groupData['members']) {
        Object.values(members).map(value => { userInviteUID = value; });
        db.collection('invites').doc(userInviteUID).update({
            invites: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ groupUID: false })})
    }
```

Not really sure what the problem is but it complains about groupUID not being used when I try to deploy it. The error I got was this:

**error TS6133: 'groupUID' is declared but its value is never read.**

I've tried:

`${groupUID}`,

```
"${groupUID}"
```

But no luck. I'm sure this is an easy problem but I'm new to typescript so don't be to harsh! Thanks!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't provide pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Since the error message is giving you a line number, it's also helpful to indicate which line of code it's referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a variable as the name of a property in an object, use the JavaScript square bracket notation.

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ [groupUID]: false })})
```